# Can a sprite(batch) have multiple "costumes" monogame

Tags: monogame

I am relatively new to game development and would like to know if a sprite can have multiple "costumes" similar to that of MIT's scratch or do I need a different sprite for each costume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the texture of something. With something like this

```
myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("filename"); // load the texture
```

Then you can draw it in your draw method with this

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White); // draw the texture
```

There is no such thing as a costume in monogame, they are just textures. The workflow in monogame is very different than scratch because there is no built in 'sprite'. You could create a sprite class if you wanted to, but is optional, and you should only do it if you have a good understanding of OOP.

```
class Sprite()
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set;}
} // you can edit this class to be more complex with other properties and methods
```

Then initialize you sprite in you Game1.cs

```
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite();
```

Load your sprite's texture like you would a normal texture in your LoadContent method

```
mySprite.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("filename");
```

And draw your sprite in your draw method

```
spriteBatch.Draw(mySprite.Texture, mySprite.Position, Color.White);
```

Comment: Just for clarification i could put each texture in a subroutine and have it set the texture to that when it is called

Comment: Yes @user181782 , you can do this but you could also change it without it being in a separate function if you don't want.